# IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState on onBackPressed();

Tags: java, android

I am not using Fragment, I am using `AppCompatActivity` and showing shared element working fine but I am facing crash on this line

```
// For Shared Element Animation same in both back press(hardware & app Bar)

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        onBackPressed();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Crash report is

```
   Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(Unknown Source:1493)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate(Unknown Source:584)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onBackPressed(Unknown Source:189)
   at android.app.Activity.onKeyUp(Activity.java:2199)
   at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2664)
   at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2441)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(Unknown Source:524)
   at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(Unknown Source:50)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.dispatchKeyEvent(Unknown Source:241)
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1996)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3909)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3883)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3416)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3466)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3435)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3542)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3443)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3599)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3416)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3466)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3435)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3443)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3416)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3466)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3435)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3575)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3759)
   at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run(InputMethodManager.java:2056)
   at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback(InputMethodManager.java:1750)
   at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent(InputMethodManager.java:1741)
   at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ImeInputEventSender.onInputEventFinished(InputMethodManager.java:2033)
   at android.view.InputEventSender.dispatchInputEventFinished(InputEventSender.java:141)
   at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(MessageQueue.java)
   at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:138)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5380)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:970)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:786)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

Comment: How does your `onBackPressed` look? Did you override it?

Comment: i didn't get you... onBackPressed i simply Call it. the crash only come on intex devices

Comment: You know that you can override that method to make it do whatever you want? That's what I was referring to.

Comment: yes cool, what line of code i use to make it bug free ???

Comment: No idea. I'm quite sorry.